# What is the minimum number of items that must be exchanged during a remove the maximum operation in a heap of size N with no duplicate keys?

Tags: algorithm, heap, priority-queue

This question I came across in Sedgewick's book. And on his website, he says that the answer is 2, however I can't understand how to achieve 2, because to remove maximum we need to first exchange the max element with the last one, decrease N, and then sink the last one down from the top into its place, which takes logN exchanges. So, how do you achieve 2?

Exchange & remove-max:

[image]

Then we need to sink, that L node, which means we need do logN more exchanges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example for 15 nodes. The idea is: have the sons of the root be large (let the left one be larger), but the other left descendants be much smaller than the right ones. Then you will only swap twice.

```
                 100
       99                   90
   9       8            89      88
7    6   5   4        87   86   85   84
```

You'll switch `84, 100` then `99, 84` and you're done. Two swaps.

For `n > 3`, after the first swap, there is no way neither of the two sons of the root won't be larger than the new root (otherwise it wasn't a heap to begin with). So you'll have to do another swap. The author most likely meant to write swaps, not items.

Comment: But he then asks "Give a heap of size 15 for which the minimum is achieved". So, I'm guessing it should be 2 for that as well, somehow.

Comment: Also in your case you did 1 exchange, and not 2.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 the question says "number of items", not "number of exchanges". My example exchanges 2 items... but 2 exchanges can also work.

Comment: oh yeah, that's right. Well, It should still be 2, somehow. For any N.

Comment: I can say that the minimum is 0, when the size of the heap is 1, because you don't need to exchange anything. What about that case?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Well, it works for 2 swaps. Check my edit.

Comment: That was my bad, I meant 2 items exchanged. And I gave you an example where the answer is 0, so your answer is not correct, sorry.

Comment: Heap size 1 is arguably not a heap, so it probably needs to be `n > 3`. For 2 items I'm not sure it's possible, I'll edit it in if I figure it out, but I think he probably meant swaps and not items.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also thinking swaps, your example is very good. N = 1 is still a heap, he was just talking general case here.

Comment: For `n > 3`, after the swap, there is no way neither of the two sons of the root won't be larger than the new root (otherwise it wasn't a heap to begin with). So you'll have to do another swap. The author meant to write swaps, not items.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the number of items that must be exchanged, not the number of  exchanges. The minimum number of exchanges is 1, and one exchange will involve 2 being exchanged.

Example:

```
       3
   1       2
```

Here, there is only one exchange between two elements: 3 and 2.